# App that uses microphone input terminates when sent to background

Tags: ios, swift, ezaudio

I have written an iOS app that gets the microphone input an analyses it. Based on the analysis, The app needs to send a notification to the user.
However, when I send the app to the background, the app gets terminated after a few seconds. I have used [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW26) and have set relevant properties in the Info.plist. Specifically the `Required background modes` key with value `App plays audio or streams audio/video using Airplay`. Any other things I need to do and missed?

Don't know if relevant but I'm using EZAudio to access the microphone.

Comment: Has the user given permission for the app to use the microphone?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You also have to enable it in *Capabilities* to work. Is *Background Modes* on? If yes, is the *Audio and AirPlay* option checked?

**Project Settings:**
[image: Project Settings]

I hope it helps!

Comment: Just to make sure, after you've made those changes (Plist + Project settings), have you _deleted_ the app from the simulator/device, _deep cleaned_ (Command+Option+Shift+K) and _built_ the project again?

Comment: yes I have.. Do you think it might be related to [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio)?

Comment: I don't think so. Have you tried to create a new project?

Answer (score 0):

if you can use `EZAudioPlotGL` class than change it `EZAudioPlot` Class it work for me. 
select `EZAudioPlotGL` view change only class name of view goto identity inspector and change it `EZAudioPlot`.
after that

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet EZAudioPlotGL *audioPlot;
```

Change it

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet EZAudioPlot *audioPlot;
```

in AppDelegate.m file change also

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier task=0;
    task=[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Expiration handler called %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);
        [application endBackgroundTask:task];
        task=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Is the EZAudioPlotGL doesn't work with background mode? I'm using it because it allows for transparent background..

Comment: in my case EZAudioPlotGL doesn't work with background mode. i have use EZaudioPlot. its works fine in background.